# Boostro.js with Angular.js and HTML content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstro

I've been trying to use the [bootstro.js](http://clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/) library to create a tour within Angular.

It works well, except when HTML is used for content. Angular directives such as ng-model and ng-change aren't working because it's not added to the DOM until called by bootstro.start().

An example of a div where bootstro will show a popover:

```
<div class="bootstro" data-bootstro-title="My popover" data-bootstro-html="true" data-bootstro-content="<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' value='' ng-model='checktest'>Check me! {{checktest}}</label></div>">
```

I expect to see: Check me! (true or false) where the state text changes when I check the box.

I've tried creating a directive using $compile, but I think bootstro is rendering the popover *after* the compile takes place, so it doesn't help. Here's my directive, used with 'boostro-fix' in the div:

```
.directive('bootstroFix', function($compile) {    
    return {
      restrict: 'A',      
      link: function(scope, element, attrs)  {   
        element.val("data-bootstro-content=" + $compile(attrs.content)(scope));
        $compile(attrs.content)(scope);
      }
    };
 })
```

Any ideas on how to bind the angular magic in this html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to get notified whenever bootstro opens a popover so that you can then tell Angular (via `$compile`) that this has happened and that it should reassociate the popover's contents with the directive scope.

From a quick look at the bootstro docs, there is an `onStep` callback that you can supply in its configuration object.

Do something like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var recompile = function () {
    // timeout to let bootstro render
    $timeout(function () {
      // get the popover bootstro inserted into the DOM
      var popoverEl = $('.bootstro').parent().find('.popover');
      $compile(popoverEl)(scope);
    }, 50);
  };

  bootstro.start(element, {
    onStep: recompile
  });

  // for the first popover
  recompile();
}
```

Comment: Dude, that worked beautifully. Thank you *very much* for the simple solution!